# Get history of queries on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get a table of *recent* slow queries on a MariaDB/MySQL server.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT/1000000000000,6) as Duration,SQL_TEXT FROM performance_schema.events_statements_current;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Duration | SQL_TEXT                                                                                                           |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0.000221 | SELECT TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT/1000000000000,6) as Duration,SQL_TEXT FROM performance_schema.events_statements_current |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

performance_schema.events_statements_current will only give me the most recent query, so my own. When I try to use `performance_schema.events_statements_history_long` I don't get much.

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Why does `current` works and not `history_long`?

Answer (score 1):

My `performance_schema.setup_consumers` was not properly set.

By default `performance_schema.events_statements_history_long` is not enabled.

```
update setup_consumers set enabled="YES" where name="events_statements_history";
update setup_consumers set enabled="YES" where name="events_statements_history_long";
```